# Evaluate $\int e^{2x}(7+e^x)^{1/2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int e^{2x}(7+e^x)^{1/2}\,dx$

Let $u=7+e^x \rightarrow du=e^xdx$

So the integral becomes:

$\int u^{\frac{3}{2}}-7u^{\frac{1}{2}}du$ and so our answer is

$\frac{2}{5}(7+e^x)^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{14}{3}(7+e^x)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$

But this is not what wolfram says. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: What is the result given by Wolfram ?

Comment: What wrench posted.. I figured it was correct just in wrong form. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int (u-7)u^{\frac{1}{2}}du
&=\frac{2}{5}(7+e^{x})^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{14}{3}(7+e^{x})^{\frac{3}{2}}+C\\
&=\frac{2}{15}(7+e^{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}(3(7+e^{x})^{2}-35(7+e^{x}))+C\\
&=\frac{2}{15}\sqrt{7+e^{x}}(7e^{x}+3e^{2x}-98)+C
\end{align}
as required.

Answer (score 2):

You could have made life simpler getting rid of the radical
$$u=\sqrt{7+e^x}\implies x=\log \left(u^2-7\right)\implies dx=\frac{2 u}{u^2-7}\,du$$
$$e^{2x}\sqrt{7+e^x}\,dx=2u^2(u^2-7)\,du$$
$$\int e^{2x}\sqrt{7+e^x}\,dx=2\int (u^4-7u^2)\,du=\frac25u^5-\frac 73 u^3+ C$$
Back to $x$
$$\int e^{2x}\sqrt{7+e^x}\,dx=\frac{2}{15} \sqrt{e^x+7} \left(3 e^{2 x}+7 e^x-98\right)+C$$